# Преобразование индекса в соответствующий элемент перечисления

Tags: java

Есть перечисление с конструктором для задания индекса дня недели.
Необходимо создать метод, преобразующий этот индекс в соответствующий день недели.

```
public enum DayOfWeek {

    MONDAY(0),
    TUESDAY(1),
    WEDNESDAY(2),
    THURSDAY(3),
    FRIDAY(4),
    SATURDAY(5),
    SUNDAY(6);

    int dayIndex;

    DayOfWeek(int dayIndex) {
        setDayIndex(dayIndex);
    }

    public int getDayIndex() {
        return dayIndex;
    }

    public void setDayIndex(int dayIndex) {
        this.dayIndex = dayIndex;
    }


    public static DayOfWeek valueOf (int index){
        //метод для преобразования индекса дня недели в соответствующий элемент перечисления.
    }
}
```

Подскажите как реализовать данный метод.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стоит воспользоваться `YOUR_ENUM.values()[index]`

Компилятор Java автоматически генерирует статический метод `values()` для каждого перечисления в java (вы не найдете метод values() в исходниках java).

Метод `values()` возвращает массив констант данного перечисление в том порядке в котором они определены. Данный метод используется при переборе элементов перечисления.

```
for (DayOfWeek p : DayOfWeek.values()) {
    System.out.printf("The day is %s, num = %d \n", p, p.getDayIndex());
}
```

В итоге метод `valueOf` будет выглядеть так:

```
public static DayOfWeek valueOf (int index){
    return DayOfWeek.values()[index];
}
```

В `Main` протестировать:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.print(DayOfWeek.valueOf(6));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь и объяснение, все заработало так, как требуется.